# For PayPal Express Checkout, how long is the token valid for?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

If a customer doesn't pay right away, can I store the token in a database and present it to them again at a later date (for example, 2 days later), so they can checkout again if they didn't complete it or didn't do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [How to Create One-Time Payments Using Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/)
>
> If the SetExpressCheckout request is successful, PayPal returns a token string in the Token response field. *The default lifetime of this token is 3 hours*

Hth...